# Change button image by clicking on the button IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, image, button

I'm to trying change the button image after tapping on it but its not working.

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
     UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
     [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vv.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
```

I have seen the many solutions which given here its not working for me please tell me is there any other way to make it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  `UIControlStateNormal`

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vv.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vv.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are after something like "toggle button" you can use the following code

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    btn.selected = !btn.selected;
}
```

previously setting up the image for the selected state in `nib`/`storyboard` or programmatically:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];  
     [self.btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vv.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

This way if you press the button again it will get back to the original image.

If you want to change image to "vv.png" for good then just use:

```
 [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vv.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: pls tell where i have setup the setbackground image code

Comment: Probably in the `nib` file or `storyboard` or, if you want to do this programmatically and have a reference to `btn` you can do in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: thanks for ur replay dariaa the above anil code worked for me

Answer (score 1):

use 
    (IBAction)click:(UIButton *)sender

instead of

```
(IBAction)click:(id)sender
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vv.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```